# Split string in multiples lines swift

Tags: string, swift, split, localizable.strings

I'm trying to split a string in multiple lines (such as the text of a song); I'm working in the localizable.strings.
I'd like to do something like this:

```
"TITLE_SONG01" = "It's my life";
"SUBTITLE_SONG01" = "";
"TEXT_SONG01" = "It's my life" +
"is now or never";
```

but it doesn't work because data isn't in the correct format. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by inserting "\n" where you want the new line to start. For example:

```
print("Hello\nWorld")
```

Which will output the `Hello` on one line and `World` on another like this:

> Hello
> World

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, it works so fine! thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.